# Rails 3.1: Possible to include jQuery from Google's CDN in application.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to know if it's possible to include an external file in the application.js file so it gets combined with the rest of the .js files in the apps/assets/javascript folder

Is there a way to get the following code work in the application.js file:

```
//= require 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'
```

or something :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? The whole idea of using a CDN is not to load content from your server but other content server. If you would like it to be compiled, just download it to the app/assets/javascripts directory and require it. It is much cleaner that way.

Comment: good point! I thought that I would still be able to load from the CDN and combine local files into the javascript once it has been loaded from the CDN but I guess that doesn't make much sense since I forgot that the Javascript is loaded directly client-side, and not server side.

Thanks for your response

Comment: I disagree with this statement entirely. Yes, your method works but the benefit of having it served up from a CDN is that it might have been served up from that CDN before and thus the client will have a cached copy of the file. 

That said, at least, IE has a limit on the max number of concurrent connections (6) to a single host.

Comment: Exactly, the point would be to load 1 less thing; though you probably don't want it included in your compiled and uglified js.  Though it would be nice if someone had a solution for conditionally requiring it if google's version isn't loaded.